# Changing portrait videos to landscape aspect with latest ffmpeg release is breaking

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am having an issue scaling videos recorded in portrait with the latest version of ffmpeg (2.1). This worked fine in a previous version, but I need the lastest version to fix a different issue.

I am trying to take any video passed and make it 852 wide by 480 high. It works fine when converting videos that are wider then tall, but when the video is taller then wide it corrupts the video. It actually adds a letter box to the top and bottom, rather then left and right. Also, the meta data shows it as the correct height & width, but its wrong when played in windows.

Here are the parameters I am using.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -s 852x480 -r 30 -aspect 1.775 -b:v 2000000 -vcodec mpeg4 -vf "scale=iw*min(852/iw\,480 /ih):ih*min(852/iw\,480 /ih),pad=852:480 :(852-iw)/2:(480 -ih)/2" -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -y OUTPUT
```

Console output from  `ffmpeg -i INPUT -r 30 -b:v 2000000 -vcodec mpeg4 -vf "scale=852:480" -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -y OUTPUT`:

```
C:\Lib>ffmpeg -i "d\ca96cd13-2995-4794-b753-22be3b918659.mov" -r 30 -b:v 2000000 -vcodec mpeg4 -vf "
scale=852:480" -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -y "d\portx.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-58015-g8cdf4e0 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 10 2013 18:04:45 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32thread
s --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-icon
v --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-
libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr -
-enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --
enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enab
le-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 52.100 / 52. 52.100
  libavcodec     55. 41.100 / 55. 41.100
  libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.102 /  3. 90.102
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'd\ca96cd13-2995-4794-b753-22be3b918659.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2013-11-12 15:02:21
    model           : iPhone 5
    model-eng       : iPhone 5
    encoder         : 7.0.2
    encoder-eng     : 7.0.2
    date            : 2013-11-12T10:02:21-0500
    date-eng        : 2013-11-12T10:02:21-0500
    make            : Apple
    make-eng        : Apple
  Duration: 00:00:15.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 780 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 480x360, 7
05 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2013-11-12 15:02:21
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-12 15:02:21
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Output #0, mp4, to 'd\portx.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    make-eng        : Apple
    model           : iPhone 5
    model-eng       : iPhone 5
    make            : Apple
    encoder-eng     : 7.0.2
    date            : 2013-11-12T10:02:21-0500
    date-eng        : 2013-11-12T10:02:21-0500
    encoder         : Lavf55.21.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 ( [0][0][0] / 0x0020), yuv420p, 852x480, q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 15360
 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2013-11-12 15:02:21
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128
 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-12 15:02:21
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  465 fps=417 q=3.8 Lsize=    4118kB time=00:00:15.52 bitrate=2173.3kbits/s
video:3860kB audio:243kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.348231%
```

Comment: You are using `-s` **and** `scale` to resize. You only need one. Also, `-aspect` is outside of your filtergraph when you should use the `setdar` filter instead. If you filter and use alternative options then it is hard to know which options get applied first. Please show the complete ffmpeg console output that goes with your command.

Comment: I am still not getting expected results. I changed my params to this and it still keeps my video with a height greater then width and it works fine with videos with a greater width then height:
    ffmpeg -i INPUT  -r 30 -b:v 2000000 -vcodec mpeg4 -vf "scale=852:480" -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -y OUTPUT

Comment: Please show the complete ffmpeg console output that goes with your command.

Comment: Added console output. If I reverse the scale numbers it actually fixes the dimensions. I think this is a bug in the new release, because this worked fine before.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`ffmpeg -i input -filter:v "scale='w=min(720,trunc((480*33/40*dar)/2+0.5)*2):h=min(480,trunc((704*40/33/dar)/2+0.5)*2)',pad='w=720:h=480:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2',setsar='r=40/33'" -target ntsc-dvd output`